# Finding averages of a list of numbers

Tags: python

```
sales = [49.99, 20, 155.20, 71.65, 91.07]

length = len(sales)
max_value = max(sales)
min_value = min(sales)
sum_of_values = sum(sales)

print(length, max_value, min_value, sum_value)

average = float(sum_of_values/length)

answer = round(average,2)

print(answer)
```

I'm trying to get a sum of the numbers in the list and then find the average, round the average to 2 decimal places, and then print it.

I am receiving this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: works fine here: 77.58. Hint: no need to convert average to float: it is already a float. and `sum_value` is not known.

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue. Aside from a NameError (`sum_value` not defined, assume you meant `sum_of_values`) the code runs as expected. Prints `77.58`

Comment: how did you call your module? can you type `print(float.__file__)` / quit your IDE and restart to get rid of parasite remaining overrides of `float` you may have made before ?

Comment: Maybe a `float = some value` before that. It's a common error for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine on my machine.

But as a suggestion:
In Python 3.4 the statistics module was introduced, which enables you to do

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> mean([1, 2, 3, 4, 4])
2.8
>>> mean([49.99, 20, 155.20, 71.65, 91.07])
77.582
```

For more infos refer to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#function-details